# How to drop column in dynamodb(nodejs)

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

what is the efficient way of dropping a column in dynamo db, should one need to set a dropping column as partition key at the time of creating a structure of a table

Answer (score 1):

dynamo db is schema less , It is strict to key attributes. If your column is a non key attribute then as my thought, column drop not required. Only you not need to add value of that column in your input json.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers, DynamoDB is a NoSQL database. It means that while creating the table, it allows to define only Partition key (mandatory) and Sort key (optional). All other non key attributes need not be defined. Even if you try to define the non key attributes, it would throw validation exception.

Other than key attributes, each item (i.e. records) can have its own attributes. Also, DynamoDB doesn't allow to have `null` or `empty` value on non-key attributes. If the attribute doesn't have any value, it can't be part of the item.

In case, if you have an attribute and you wanted to remove it from the item, you can use **REMOVE** keyword on update expression.

> REMOVE - Removes one or more attributes from an item.

**Example:-**

The below example removes `info` attribute from an item.

```
var params = {
    TableName:table,
    Key:{
        "year": year,
        "title": title
    },
    UpdateExpression: "remove info",
    ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"
};

docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to update item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("UpdateItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamo db is not the SQL database(columnar database) instead it is NoSql Database, the only out for removing the column from dynamo db is

1.Create a backup table from original table
2.Create another Model with parameter removed from original model(used for 3.storing data in original table).
4.Delete the original table.
5.Create a new table.
6.Fetch the data from backup table in Original model.
7.Convert the data from Original model to New Model(having column removed)
8.Insert the data in new table with New Model.

If data is high in backup table then use pagination for fetching the data from original one.